# find Camera Center with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, homography

I'm trying to get the camera center from a calibrated camera. 
I have 4 measured 3D objectPoints and its images and trying to get the center (translation) from the projective matrix with no acceptable results.
Any advise regarding the accuracy I should expect with opencv? Should I increase the number of points?

These are the results I got:

```
TrueCenter in mm for XYZ
 [[4680.]
 [5180.]
 [1621.]] 
Center
 [[-2508.791]
 [ 6015.98 ]
 [-1096.674]]
```

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy.linalg import inv

TrueCameraCenter = np.array([4680., 5180, 1621]).reshape(-1,1)

objectPoints = np.array(
        [[   0., 5783., 1970.],
           [   0., 5750., 1261.],
           [   0., 6412., 1968.],
           [1017., 9809., 1547.]], dtype=np.float32)

imagePoints=np.array(
        [[ 833.75, 1097.25],
           [ 798.  , 1592.25],
           [1323.  , 1133.5 ],
           [3425.5 , 1495.5 ]], dtype=np.float32)

cameraMatrix= np.array(
        [[3115.104,   -7.3  , 2027.605],
           [   0.   , 3077.283, 1504.034],
           [   0.   ,    0.   ,    1.   ]])

retval, rvec, tvec = cv2.solvePnP(objectPoints, imagePoints,cameraMatrix,None, None, None, False, cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)
R,jac= cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)
imagePoints2,jac= cv2.projectPoints(objectPoints, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix,None)
print('TrueCenter in mm for XYZ\n', TrueCameraCenter, '\nCenter\n', -inv(R).dot(tvec))
```

Comment: You're using a very simple camera lens model which is probably not that accurate around the edges of the image, this won't be helping. Also the number of point pairs is less important than their distribution, if they are clustered in any direction then you're camera position estimate will be negatively effected.

Comment: Thanks @PeteBlackerThe3rd. I used 4 coplanar with no 3 colinear points and improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this interesting presentation regarding the Location Determination Problem by Bill Wolfe. [Perspective View Of 3 Points](http://faculty.csuci.edu/william.wolfe/csuci/Articles/PerspectiveView/P3P.ppt)

So, using 4 non-coplanar points (non 3 colinear) the solution improved.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy.linalg import inv,norm


TrueCameraCenter = np.array([4680., 5180, 1621])
objectPoints = np.array(
        [[   0., 5783., 1970.],
       [   0., 5750., 1261.],
       [   0., 6412., 1968.],
       [   0., 6449., 1288.]])

imagePoints=np.array(
        [[ 497.5 ,  674.75],
       [ 523.75, 1272.5 ],
       [1087.75,  696.75],
       [1120.  , 1212.5 ]])

cameraMatrix= np.array(
        [[3189.096,    0.   , 2064.431],
         [   0.   , 3177.615, 1482.859],
         [   0.   ,    0.   ,    1.   ]])
dist_coefs=np.array([[ 0.232, -1.215, -0.002,  0.011,  1.268]])

retval, rvec, tvec = cv2.solvePnP(objectPoints, imagePoints,cameraMatrix,dist_coefs, 
                                  None, None, False, cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)
R,_= cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)
C=-inv(R).dot(tvec).flatten()
print('TrueCenter in mm for XYZ\n', TrueCameraCenter, '\nCenter\n',C.astype(int) )
print('Distance:', int(norm(TrueCameraCenter-C)))
```

[image]